# Licensing: distributing open source components with your PyPI package

Tags: mit, distribution, python

I have developed a Python package capable of generating a web page with some embedded tables and figures. The web page employs some open source components (namely Angular.js, Bootstrap and font-awesome, all of them licensed under MIT license).

I want the web page to be "standalone": I want users to be able to view the web page even if they have no Internet access. So ATM I am including the minified versions of these projects in my package, and I copy them together with the generated files to produce the final web page.

I want to ship my package to PyPI. My question is: is it acceptable for a PyPI package to include these projects? Do I have to do anything like including any copyright/license notice for these projects in my package? (I am pretty new to licensing).

I want to release my project under MIT license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it acceptable for a PyPI package to include these projects?

Yes.

> Do I have to do anything like including any copyright/license notice for these projects in my package?

The files themselves should include a license header.
However, you could include a statement in your README
that lists the bundled files.

> I want to release my project under MIT license.

Using the same license definitely makes this simpler.